# Exam in sql transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am a university student and the previous week I had an exam on sql transactions. One of the problems that I couldn't solve was the following:

We consider the table

**employees** `(employee_number, last_name, salary)`.

a. In Microsoft SQL server running simultaneously (concurrent data access) the following transactions in the table 1. Assuming that the table is initially empty, what will be the contents after the completion of the table one transaction;

b. Even now the transactions of Table 2. Assuming that the table is initially empty what is the contents after the completion of Table 2 transactions;

c. Even now the transactions of Table 3. Assuming that the table contains records resulting from step 2, what will be the contents after the completion of the transactions table 3;

Tables(1-2-3)
[image]

> TIP:The Microsoft SQL SERVER requires locks on objects in the database in which modifications are made.

Any suggestions for the solution so I can have it for the next time?

Comment: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* http://stackoverflow.com/help Also: Don't include text as an image.

Comment: What do *you* think the answers are?

Comment: you missed adding `the following transactions in the table 1`..

Comment: @TheGameiswar the following transaction in the table 1 means the table 1 in the photo